# How to check the contains in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2. I need to check whether the column value has `"-"` or not at the same time, I'm using the `case` statement to used here.

If the `"-"` is present then I need to change the date format to `dd/mm/yy`. The given date in the database is `"2013-01-01 00:00:00.000" to "dd/mm/yy"`

Do you have any idea about that ?

My code is:

```
select  
    DISTINCT 
    D30.SPGD30_SHIP_SITE_C As ShipSite, D30.SPGD30_RATING_MONTH_Y As RatingMonth,
    D30.SPGD30_PRIOR_SCORE_R As Prior, D30.SPGD30_REVISED_SCORE_R As Revised, 
    CASE 
      WHEN SUBSTRING(D30.SPGD30_TRACKED_ADJUSTMENT_X, 1, 1) = 'D' 
        THEN 'Dispute - ' + D30.SPGD30_TRACKED_ADJUSTMENT_X 
      WHEN SUBSTRING(D30.SPGD30_TRACKED_ADJUSTMENT_X, 1, 1) = 'R' 
        THEN 'Return Of Points - '+D30.SPGD30_TRACKED_ADJUSTMENT_X
      WHEN containstable(D30.SPGD30_TRACKED_ADJUSTMENT_X, '"*-" or "-*"') 
        THEN 'Score Calculation - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), D30.SPGD30_TRACKED_ADJUSTMENT_X, 1)
    END AS Adjustments,
    J02.SPGJ02_MSG_CODE_X As Comments,
    D31.SPGA04_RATING_ELEMENT_D As Comments,
    D30.SPGD30_LAST_TOUCH_Y As LastUpdated,
    D30.SPGD30_LAST_TOUCH_C As LastUpdatedCDSID 
FROM
    CSPGD30_TRACKING D30, CSPGD31_TRACKING_RATING_ELEMNT D31,
    CSPGA04_RATING_ELEMENT_MSTR A04 , CSPGJ02_MSG_OBJ J02, CSPGJ03_MSG_TRANSLN J03
WHERE
    D30.SPGD30_SHIP_SITE_C = D31.SPGD30_SHIP_SITE_C -- D30 and D31
    AND D30.SPGD30_RATING_MONTH_Y = D31.SPGD30_RATING_MONTH_Y --D30 and D31
    AND D31.SPGA04_RATING_ELEMENT_D = A04.SPGA04_RATING_ELEMENT_D --D31 and A04
    AND J02.SPGJ02_MSG_K = J03.SPGJ02_MSG_K --J02 and J03
    AND A04.SPGJ02_MSG_K = J02.SPGJ02_MSG_K --A04 and Jo2
    AND d30.SPGA02_BUSINESS_TYPE_C = 'prod' -- org
    AND d30.SPGA03_REGION_C = 'EU' -- region
    AND d30.SPGD30_SHIP_SITE_C = 'ms01a' -- shipsite
    AND D30.SPGD30_LAST_TOUCH_Y BETWEEN '2013-01-01 00:00:00.000'  --rating month
                                    AND '2013-01-30 23:59:59.000' -- rating month
    AND d30.SPGD30_LAST_TOUCH_C = 'sadalara' --CDSID
```

Comment: Is the question, "I am storing a string representation of a date in a varchar column. Sometimes a dash is used as the delimiter. I need to display that string with a slash instead of a dash. How to do it?" Or is the column a bona-fide date column?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**20 years** ago!). ***Please*** stop using it

Answer (score 4):

Just use [CHARINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) to test

```
...
when CHARINDEX('-*', D30.SPGD30_TRACKED_ADJUSTMENT_X) > 0 OR
  CHARINDEX('*-', D30.SPGD30_TRACKED_ADJUSTMENT_X) > 0

THEN 'Score Calculation - '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), D30.SPGD30_TRACKED_ADJUSTMENT_X, 1)
```

FYI, you need [style 103 for `dd/mm/yyyy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a87d0850-c670-4720-9ad5-6f5a22343ea8)

Comment: thanks for your reply i need the date format of dd/mm/yy..do you have any idea about that.. in addition to that the convert function is not working.

Comment: @Adalarasan_THINK-BIG: I am. But what data is in PGD30_TRACKED_ADJUSTMENT_X? what datatype? what formats?

Comment: If the `"-"` is present then I need to change the date format to `dd/mm/yy`. The given date in the database is `"2013-01-01 00:00:00.000" to "Score Calculation - dd/mm/yy"`